How to upload file to external data source with salesforce connect
This has been asked once or twice on this sub, but none of them has a solid answer yet.  I am looking to upload files from Salesforce (communities) to an external data source (SharePoint/OneDrive).   Research tells me that while Files Connect is not bi-directional, it is possible via REST API and Salesforce Connect but I am yet to find a post that explains how it was achieved.
@RavikantKedia Has posted about uploading files to Google Drive from Salesforce, but it is unclear whether he was successful.
Can anyone provide insight as to whether a sync from Salesforce to external data drive is possible and how?
TIA

3rd party authored integrations on AppExchange are likely your best. Mulesoft has a Google Drive connector but we've never used it, caveat emptor.
